# Structure-bound std::tuple breaks std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream, stdtuple

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>

auto read_data(std::ifstream& training_file) {
    if (!training_file) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Error: could not open one or more files"};
    }

    std::stringstream training{};
    training << training_file.rdbuf();

    std::cout << training.str() << '\n';

    return std::tie(training);
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream input{"input.txt"};

    auto [train] = read_data(input);

    std::cout << train.str() << '\n';
    std::cout << "x" << '\n';
}
```

And ignore the fact that I am returning a single element with `std::tie` (originally I am `tie`ing two `std::stringstream` objects, but that's not needed for the MCVE).

The `input.txt` file looks like this:

> ```
> 0,0,0,0,
> 0,0,0,0,
> ```

Note - the is no line break after the second line.

The unexpected output of this program is:

> ```
> 0,0,0,0,
> 0,0,0,0,
> É$~      Ź     ,
> x
> ```

Obviously, the `É$~      Ź     ,` part should not have been there.

Notice that I am outputting the very same file contents. I am clueless where did the unexpected part come from.

It gets even stranger when playing with the code. If I comment out the `std::cout << train.str() << '\n';` in `main()` and duplicate the `std::cout << training.str() << '\n';` line in `read_data()` function, the output is as expected:

> ```
> 0,0,0,0,
> 0,0,0,0,
> 0,0,0,0,
> 0,0,0,0,
> x
> ```

So it's not causaed by calling `std::stringstream::str` twice. It must be caused by the usage of the returned value.

What's more? Executing the `std::cout << train.str() << '\n';` line from `main()` *twice* results in program termination with `code 3`.

GDB reports:

```
gdb: unknown target exception 0x80000001 at 0x7ff909e845c0
Thread 1 received signal ?, Unknown signal.
0x00007ff909e845c0 in ?? ()
```

But it **still does not end here**. If I change the file content to contain either:

```
0 0
```

or

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

the output is again as expected (using the original code - one `cout` in `read_data()` and one in `main()`.

To make sure I wasn't being tricked by some non-printable character that snuck into my file, I used PowerShell to output its Hex representation, which resulted in the following sequence regarding the original file content:

```
30 20 30 20 30 20 30 0D 0A 30 20 30 20 30 20 30
```

As you can see, nothing except for `0`s, spaces and `carriage-return + line-feed` is in my file.

Any idea why this could be happening? For the full information, I am using GCC 8.2.0 from MinGW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a local:

```
std::stringstream training{};
```

This returns a reference to said local, wrapped in a tuple:

```
return std::tie(training);
```

So `auto [train] = ...;` initializes the name `train` to be a dangling reference. The behavior of the program is undefined.

---

If you need to return two streams ( or more ) then just predaclare them in the tuple/array/custom aggregate of your choice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

auto read_data() {
    std::array<std::stringstream,2> trainings{
        std::stringstream{},
        std::stringstream{}
    };

    return trainings;
}

int main() {

    auto train = read_data();

    std::cout << train[1].str() << '\n';
    std::cout << "x" << '\n';
}
```

[Live Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb7277b61ead7836)

Copy elision guarantees the extra object will either be removed altogether or move constructed into place.

Comment: Well yeah, that was indeed silly. Any idea for the elegant way of returning two `std::stringstream`s from the function? Can `std::tuple` store the objects themselves? I suspect there will be problems since `std::stringstream` is uncopyable. Can I `move` it to a wrapper and return it?

Comment: @Fureeish - Just return by value. The copy elision algorithm will either get rid of the the extra object altogether, or will move construct it at the target.

Comment: That would be great if I had only *one* `std::stringstream` to return (as in the original question), but I noted that I originally used `std::tie` since I create *two* streams and I would like to return both of them and refer to them with structured bindings. EDIT: of course I *could* just call the `read_data` twice and store the result in variables, but I really would like to know the way to achieve the original goal, even if it's after all not the preferred way of doing things

Comment: Thank you! It's extremely useful especially since one *can* use structured bindings with arrays (and with `std::array`). Wish I could upvote and accept twice!